# Cannot install canvas on npm

Tags: node.js, node-canvas

I am trying to install canvas on my raspberry pi via npm after successfully installing on my main pc, but now I get a really long error that I don't know how to fix.
Here's the full error:

```
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Package pixman-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pixman-1.pc'
npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
npm ERR! No package 'pixman-1' found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:261:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.32+
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary" "--module=/home/alex/discord-bot/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/home/alex/discord-bot/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/alex/discord-bot/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.16.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/home/alex/discord-bot/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/home/alex/discord-bot/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/alex/discord-bot/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.32+
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/alex/discord-bot/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/alex/discord-bot/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.16.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.9
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/alex/.npm/_logs/2022-08-09T20_08_23_632Z-debug-0.log
```

I used the command npm install --build-from-source canvas, please can I have help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems you're missing the 'pixman' dependency. Did you follow the [guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) to install all the needed dependencies before installing canvas? It requires a bunch of [dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adMHR.png).

Comment: This is the right answer !

Comment: Linking to an image of otherwise perfectly copy-pastable commands has to be one of the most infuriating things you can do. Please fix it and actually link to the page that screenshot was taken from.

Comment: still relevant.

Answer (score 16):

Try this before run npm install canvas. It work for me

```
brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg
```

Ref : https://flaviocopes.com/fix-node-canvas-error-pre-gyp-macos/

Comment: It worked for me as well `brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg`

Answer (score 1):

You have to install required dependencies for compiling your system from  https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas

For ubuntu i did

`sudo apt-get install build-essential libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev librsvg2-dev`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it's resolved by manually installing packages inside of canvas.

Apparently if you set NPM to ignore scripts, which prevents node-pre-gyp from downloading prebuilt binaries. I accessed to canvas folder in node_modules and then manually run node-gyp rebuild and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**1 Install Dependencies:**
Install the required dependencies using Homebrew. Open a terminal and run the following commands:

> brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib

**2 Set PKG_CONFIG_PATH:**
Export PKG_CONFIG_PATH to include the directory containing pixman-1.pc. Add the following line to your shell profile file (e.g., ~/.zshrc or ~/.bashrc):

> export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/pixman/lib/pkgconfig"

Then, restart your terminal or run:

> source ~/.zshrc   # or source ~/.bashrc if you are using bash

**3 Reinstall Node Modules:**
Remove the node_modules directory and package-lock.json file from your project and then reinstall the dependencies:

> rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json npm install