# create react project with create-react-app but error

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, node-pre-gyp

I try to create a react demo with create-react-app but it always error, my node -v is 18.17.1 and it is mac m1, thanks for your help!

```
Creating a new React app in /Users/gengyinshan/gys/kwr-chrome-extension.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template-typescript...

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/gengyinshan/gys/kwr-chrome-extension/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --update-binary
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/Users/gengyinshan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/node /Users/gengyinshan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/Users/gengyinshan/gys/kwr-chrome-extension/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/gengyinshan/gys/kwr-chrome-extension/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=9 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v108-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! Package pixman-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pixman-1.pc'
npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
npm ERR! No package 'pixman-1' found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/gengyinshan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:325:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/Users/gengyinshan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/node" "/Users/gengyinshan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary" "--module=/Users/gengyinshan/gys/kwr-chrome-extension/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/Users/gengyinshan/gys/kwr-chrome-extension/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=9" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v108"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/gengyinshan/gys/kwr-chrome-extension/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.17.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/Users/gengyinshan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/node /Users/gengyinshan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/Users/gengyinshan/gys/kwr-chrome-extension/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/gengyinshan/gys/kwr-chrome-extension/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=9 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/gengyinshan/gys/kwr-chrome-extension/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.1.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/Users/gengyinshan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/node" "/Users/gengyinshan/gys/kwr-chrome-extension/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/gengyinshan/gys/kwr-chrome-extension/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v18.17.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.11
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/gengyinshan/.npm/_logs/2023-09-25T22_49_47_655Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template-typescript has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting kwr-chrome-extension/ from /Users/gengyinshan/gys
Done.
```

I have try to change node version, npm cache clean --force and it still failed!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message provided, it seems that the issue is related to the installation of the node-canvas package. Specifically, the error message mentions that the package pixman-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path, and that there was a call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' that returned an exit status of 1 while trying to load binding.gyp. This error message is similar to those reported [here](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1733) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73297594/cannot-install-canvas-on-npm), which suggest that the issue may be related to the installation of dependencies such as pkg-config, cairo, pango, libpng, jpeg, giflib, and librsvg.

Since you're using a Mac M1, try this

```
brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg
```